# Visualforce page only show list of 20

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardsetcontroller

I've created a class and VF markup to try and pull phone extensions from a custom object to display of our homepage. The code words well except it limits the results to only 20. Is there a way to tell it to display all records?

```
public class GetExtensions {
// ApexPages.StandardSetController must be instantiated
// for standard list controllers
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Id, Name, Extension__c FROM SFDC_Employee__c WHERE Title__c != 'Podiatrist' AND Employee_Status__c = 'Active (Commenced)' AND Location__c = 'Head Office' ORDER BY Name ASC]));

        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

// Initialize setCon and return a list of records
public List<SFDC_Employee__c> getextensions() {
    return (List<SFDC_Employee__c>) setCon.getRecords();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste your code? Also can you check how many records are displayed if you open it directly by going to '/apex/yourPageName'?

Comment: Thanks for the help. custom controller added to question

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and the following solution worked for me, adding setPageSize(setCon.getResultSize()):

```
// Initialize setCon and return a list of records
public List<SFDC_Employee__c> getextensions() {
    setCon.setPageSize(setCon.getResultSize());
    return (List<SFDC_Employee__c>) setCon.getRecords();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can only show 20 records at a time using recordsetvar use custom controller to show more.

Comment: Please provide some official documentation to prove your answer. Thank you.